# Get the right day spelling in the query

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have two tables `stops` and `arrivaltimes` I want to put the right spelling ´mon-fri´ or `sat` or `sun` in the query what is the best way to manage that in java? for example today is monday if the stop's name is `ABC` weekday is `Monday` and the current time equal `10:43` to the arrivaltime I want to get just the route number `9`

This query works fine but I dont know how to get the day spelling in:

```
SELECT route from arrivaltimes 
  INNER JOIN stops ON arrivaltimes.stop_id=stops.stop_id 
  WHERE weekday = "+ day +" 
    and time_format(arrivaltime,'%H:%i')= time_format(curtime() ,'%H:%i') 
    and name LIKE stop_name
```

---

[image]

[image]

my code:

```
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, user, password);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    // Create a statement
    Statement stt = con.createStatement();

    DatabaseMetaData dbm = con.getMetaData();

    ResultSet stopsExist = dbm.getTables(null, null, "stops", null);

    if (stopsExist.next()) {
        // the stops and arrrivaltimes tables exist.

        PreparedStatement preparedLatLong = con
                .prepareStatement("SELECT lat, longi from stops");
        ResultSet rsLatLong = preparedLatLong.executeQuery();
        while (rsLatLong.next()) {
            double lat_stop = rsLatLong.getDouble("lat");
            double lon_stop = rsLatLong.getDouble("longi");
            double distStops = haversineDistance(latD, longD, lat_stop,
                    lon_stop);
            if (distStops <= 10) {
                String stop_name = rsLatLong.getString("name");
                PreparedStatement preparedTime = con
                        .prepareStatement("SELECT route from arrivaltimes INNER JOIN stops"
                                + " ON arrivaltimes.stop_id=stops.stop_id "
                                + "WHERE weekday = "+ day +" and time_format(arrivaltime,'%H:%i')= time_format(curtime() ,'%H:%i') and name LIKE"
                                + stop_name);

                ResultSet rsArrivaletime = preparedTime.executeQuery();
                 routeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                while (rsArrivaletime.next()) {
                    int route = rsArrivaletime.getInt("route");
                    routeList.add(route);

                }
            }
            break;
        }
```

Comment: `weekday = '"+ day +"'` need to be in single quote.

Comment: @Abhik: as well the stop_name? my problem at the moment how to get the right day's spelling in my table in the query? since `day` at the moment is just a number.

Comment: It would be better to have a table that is properly designed and not based just on human-readable data. That is, a table that has a `startWeekDay` and `endWeekDay` that contain numbers. It's better for queries, and for display purposes it's easy to convert.